# Mathematical expression recognition using image processing in c#

Tags: c#, opencv, ocr

I'm developing an image processing application for document reading for vision impaired people. In that there's a part for identifying mathematical formula.I'm using **Teseract OCR** for character recognition but I don't have an idea how to recognize mathematical formulas. Is there any method to identify mathematical formulas included in that given document.

I'm using C#,Open CV and visual studio 2015 to code.

Comment: Not so easy... [A lot to study ;D](http://www.inftyproject.org/en/articles_ocr.html)

Comment: Thank you for the research papers @Miki ...